# EmberJS - Multiple hasMany relationship on same attribute

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have below json and I want to add multiple has many relationship.

```
{
   "Id": "2311",
   "package": [
          {
            "0": "233123"
          }, 
          {
             "1": "1987797"
          }
       ]
}
```

I want something like this in my model.

```
package : hasMany('package'),
package : hasMany('name'),
```

How can I use the hasMany relationship on same attribute for 2 models ?

Comment: First of all that isn’t valid JSON. If you control the server returning the JSON response, you can make the change there.

Comment: That JSON was just an idea to explain question. I have corrected the JSON in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

When you define hasMany relationship, for example, a client hasMany packages, you get the following representation in your database:

```
Client 1 { // Client model hasMany relationship to Package model
  name: "client1"
  id: "1234" 
}

Package 1 {
  name: "package1"
  id: "233123"
  client: "1234" // this package belongs to client 1
}

Package 2 {
  name: "package2"
  id: "1987797"
  client: "1234" // this package also belongs to client 1
}
```

Are you saying you want your Client model to hold 2 hasMany relationships, one for the Package name and one for the Package ID?

Please provide a bit more detail and I'll help you answer the question.